# How to split a String using | as the regex?

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

Im running this code and getting the wrong output.
It seems like | as the expression in split is giving wrong output

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "Hi, |+nl+|+nl+| split me please";
    String[] sArr = s.split("|");

    for (String sa : sArr) {
        System.out.println(sa);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
H
i
,

|
+
n
l
+
|
+
n
l
+
|

s
p
l
i
t

m
e

p
l
e
a
s
e
```

How can I split it properly that it gets split this way?
Hi, 
+n1+
+n1+
and so forth

Answer (score 0):

You may have to escape the |.

```
String[] sArr = s.split("\\|");
```